Upgrade to node18, and Server was keep failing with ECONNRESET
Has anyone faced the same issue, when I upgraded our web server to use node 18. The server kept failing to handle incoming requests with
code: ECONNRESET

See the full error stack below:
"err":{"type":"Error","message":"aborted","stack":"Error: aborted\n    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:717:14)\n    at abortIncoming (node:_http_server:754:17)\n    at socketOnClose (node:_http_server:748:3)\n    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)\n    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)\n    at node:net:322:12\n    at Socket.done (node:_tls_wrap:588:7)\n    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)\n    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)\n    at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)","code":"ECONNRESET"}

For some background information, our server configured to use tls1.2's policy file, and I did not even think this is related with NLB's issue. Just for some references.
My question is, should I add more error listeners to this type of error to get better understanding? Appreciate any kind of hints.
Thanks,
Coffee Maker
We should either log more useful information or see if this abort error get mitigated in the server
